# Convert binary coordinates to decimal ASN.1 UPER

Tags: binary, coordinates, asn.1

I cannot convert correctly binary numbers to decimal using ASN.1 compilation. Those binaries correspond with lat and long.

lat `1001110010100100101010110011111`

long `01101100100101011100100100111000`

If I convertem to decimal I get `1314018719` and `1821755704`, respectively. However, the coordinates should be this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YqoH.png)

I've tried multiple converters but without exit. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't how you think the encoding works.  ASN.1 PER is specified by ITU-T X.680 and ITU-T X.691.  (UPER is unaligned PER, a variant of PER defined in the same specs.) The rules for integers include doing things such as encoding as an offset from a lower bound, using a length determinant and minimal octets, using a fixed number of octets and no length determinant, etc., depending on the INTEGER type's constraints.  Nobody can tell you how to treat the data you've provided without having the ASN.1 schema and knowing what part of it relates to this data, as well as knowing whether the bits you have include the length determinant or not (if there is one).